# Upgrading Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8 Pro: What features am I going to lose?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I know by upgrading from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8 Pro that I will lose the following features:

- Windows XP Mode
- Windows DVD Maker
- DVD playback
- Windows Media Center
- Built in games for Windows 7 (Chess Titans, Purble Place, etc.)
- Aero, Start Menu, etc.

What other features am I going to lose by upgrading to Windows 8 Pro?

Comment: Do you have hardware (printers, scanners etc) which have only windows 7 drivers? If you do that you are going to loose use of these until drivers are written. If it is older hardware that may never happen.

Comment: For a limited time the [Media Center Feature Pack](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs) is free. So you may be able to cross off media center off the list if you can get it before the offer is over (January 31, 2013).

Comment: Nothing, provided you install the Media Center Upgrade.

Comment: ...Your sanity.

Comment: Do you really want to go through a downgrade?

Comment: Here is a GREAT article that lists your answer...  http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/156585-features-and-options-removed-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Shadow Copies / Previous Versions (replaced by File History)
- Universal Spell Checking
- Natural Language Search
- Multiple Clipboards
- Windows Explorer (command bar is gone and replaced with a ribbon UI. Now referred to as File Explorer)
- Windows Update Desktop Notifications
- Windows Desktop Gadgets
- Flip 3D
- File Manager tab support
- BSOD details & technical information (screen look changed)
- Desktop Pen, Ink and Touch Input
- Windows CardSpace
- People Near Me P2P API

---

You can also check [**The complete list of features removed in Windows 8**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_8) Wikipedia article for all the details.

Comment: Actually Windows 8 has the same Backup and Restore applet as it was in Windows 7.

Comment: The option for Word and other Microsoft programs to 'Print to File' has been replaced in Windows 8 by PortPrompt

Comment: Sounds like a downgrade!!

Comment: @MattH Not necessarily. [Windows 8 includes lots of new features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_8). Whether Windows 8 is an improvement from Windows 7, is really subjective.

Comment: Had a bit of a play with it... the "Modern UI" is rather ugly. Maybe this is Linux's big break.

Answer (score 2):

Some installed software might be incompatible, The [upgrade assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8) will give you a list after scanning.

Comment: I read somewhere that it is compatible with drivers for Vista and 7.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of what software features I will lose in the base OS, but this is a good thing to note as well.

Comment: @cowgod - the upgrade assistance points this out.

Comment: I had to uninstall (completely) and then reinstall my AMD drivers for my graphics card before that worked properly after upgrading 7 Pro to 8 Pro. But otherwise, drivers aren't really an issue when updating.